# PHP Preg match on html file. Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to put the French words in a Array.

```
<?php

$contents = file_get_contents("http://quizlet.com/9117/envol-7-unite-1-presentation-flash-cards/"); 

$pattern = '/<span class="TermText qWord lang-fr">(.*?)</s';

preg_match($pattern,$contents, $matches);

print_r($matches); 

?>
```

The result of this code is a empty Array.

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags 2) That string doesn't seem to appear on that URL provided. (The string in the source uses single quote encapsulation for the class definition, for reference).

Comment: @JonStirling, for your #2 comment, the string does exist on line 895

Comment: @CodeGodie No it doesn't. Look more closely.

Comment: Ahh.. it does exist, except it has single quotes `'` rather than double quotes `"`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The source page encloses class values in single quotes. Also you need to use `preg_match_all()` function to get all results.

```
<?php

$contents = file_get_contents("http://quizlet.com/9117/envol-7-unite-1-presentation-flash-cards/"); 

$pattern = "/<span class='TermText qWord lang-fr'>(.*?)\</s";

preg_match_all($pattern,$contents, $matches);

print_r($matches); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all inner texts of `<span>` tags having `lang-fr` in their `class` attribute value, you can use the following DOMDocument/DOMXPath based solution:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://quizlet.com/9117/envol-7-unite-1-presentation-flash-cards/");
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($contents, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$spans = $xp->query('//span[contains(@class,"lang-fr")]');
$arr = array();
foreach ($spans as $span) {
 array_push($arr, $span->nodeValue);
}
print_r($arr);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/9jj0N9)

The xpath is `'//span[contains(@class,"lang-fr")]'` here. You can make it stricter to only get all span tags with class attribute value equal to "TermText qWord lang-fr": `'//span[@class="lang-fr"]'`.

This solution relieves you from the problem of matching this or that type of delimiting attribute values in HTML. And many other issues related to regex HTML parsing.